# jBPM 6.2 - Unable to add comment while completing task

Tags: java, jbpm

I am unable to add comment to the task while completing it. In jBPM 5, there was a method called "addComment" in TaskClient. How can I add task in jBPM 6.2. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
Comment taskComment = new CommentImpl();
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//params.put("Comment", actorId+" completed the task#"+taskId);
params.put("assignedTo", user.getUsername());
params.put("description", documentUUID);

workflowUtil.completeTask(taskId, actorId, params);
Task task=workflowUtil.getTask(taskId);
task.getTaskData().getComments().add(taskComment) ;
```

what should I do to persist this comment for retrieving it later.

Answer (score 0):

The taskservice or internal taskservice is providing that method, so you should be able to do the same as you are doing inside the completeTask method.

Answer (score 0):

You can `add`, `delete` and `getallcomments` for a task using `TaskService.execute()`, as demonstrated below:

```
org.kie.api.task.TaskService taskService = runtimeEngine.getTaskService();
taskService.execute(new AddCommentCommand(taskId, comment));
taskService.execute(new DeleteCommentCommand(taskId, comment));
taskService.execute(new GetAllCommentsCommand(taskId));
```